# Delphi - Connect to Teradata DB (on virtual machine) with FireDAC

Tags: delphi, teradata, firedac

Cut to the chase:
Windows 10 x64 host machine runs VMWare Player 12 which runs 'TDE 16.00.04 SLES 11' linux OS downloaded from teradata website. The virtual machine is pre-installed with teradata DB and it works fine, I can connect to it with Teradata Studio Express from the host machine.
(Also there is an adhoc.c file which can help you to test the ODBC connectivity on the VM and it also works fine).
I've downloaded and installed the 'Teradata ODBC Driver For Windows' from teradata site.
Using **Delphi Berlin 10.1** I've created a new project, added **TFDConnection** component and **TFDPhysTDataDriverLink** component to the main form, added button to set connection string and to connect to DB. 
Set the TFDPhysTDataDriverLink ODBCDriver property to 'Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.00'. Set connection string:

```
Connection.Params.Values['DriverID']  := 'TData';
Connection.Params.Values['Server']    := '192.168.56.128';
Connection.Params.Values['Database']  := 'dbc';
Connection.Params.Values['User_Name'] := 'dbc';
Connection.Params.Values['Password']  := 'dbc';
```

When I try to connect, the exception I've got says nothing:
`[FireDAC][Phys][ODBC]`
(Yes, thats all, nothing else)
I've also tried add User and System DSN entry (32bit) and tried to set the Datasource param:

```
Connection.Params.Values['DriverID']  := 'TData';
Connection.Params.Values['Datasource']:= 'testdsn';
Connection.Params.Values['User_Name'] := 'dbc';
Connection.Params.Values['Password']  := 'dbc';
```

When I do this, the error msg says:

```
Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

How can I properly setup the connection from delphi? How can I get info about the problem?
Any ideas what can be the problem?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to connect from the IDE?

Comment: @Victoria: I've tried to use FireDAC explorer. Added new connection, DriverID: TData etc. The info tabs says:  Loading driver TData ...  Loading odbc32.dll driver manager
  Creating ODBC environment handle
  Searching for ODBC driver ...
    Checking for ODBC driver [Teradata] ...
    Error: specified ODBC drivers are not found

Comment: I see. You might have installed 64-bit ODBC driver (because the IDE can be only 32-bit as far as I remember). So you might be out of luck with this option (though it's the first thing I would try). So your app. and driver are 64-bit, right?

Comment: Are you sure you specified the 32-bit DSN and not 64-bit? The admin for these two looks exactly the same, but they're visible to two different Windows subsystems.

Comment: First I install both 32 and 64 drivers, set both 32 and 64 the exactly same DSN just to be sure. No success. Then I remove the drivers and install only 32. Still no success.

Comment: @Victoria no, my app is 32bit and the driver too..

Comment: FWIW, we're getting the same error with the ODBC link as well. I've also tried setting up a UDL file against the ODBC datasource, and it consistently returns "Unspecified Error" when testing the connection - this looks very much like a teradata ODBC driver issue.